# Is $ f(x) = \log(1 + x^2)$ uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

> Is $f(x) = \log (1 +x^2) $ uniformly continious on $\mathbb{R}$? Yes/No.

My attempt : yes

Let $\Delta y:=x-y$, so that $x=y+\Delta y$. Then
$$
\frac{1+x^2}{1+y^2}=\frac{1+y^2+2y\Delta y+(\Delta y)^2}{1+y^2}=1+\frac{2y\Delta y}{1+y^2}+\frac{(\Delta y)^2}{1+y^2}.
$$
From here, we can note that for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
\left\lvert\frac{2y}{1+y^2}\right\rvert\leq 1\qquad\text{and}\qquad\left\lvert\frac{1}{1+y^2}\right\rvert\leq 1.
$$

(The second inequality is immediate; for the first try considering $\lvert y\rvert\leq 1$ and $\lvert y\rvert>1$ as separate cases.

But, as a result,
$$
\left\lvert\frac{1+x^2}{1+y^2}-1\right\rvert\leq\left\lvert\frac{2y}{1+y^2}\right\rvert\lvert\Delta y\rvert+\left\lvert\frac{1}{1+y^2}\right\rvert(\Delta y)^2\leq\lvert\Delta y\rvert+(\Delta y)^2.
$$
we can definitely make this last expression small by making $\Delta y$ small... and note that $\lvert\Delta y\rvert<\delta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can observe that$$(\forall x\in\mathbb R):\bigl\lvert f'(x)\bigr\rvert=\left\lvert\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\right\rvert\leqslant1.$$It follows from this and from the Mean Value Theorem that$$\lvert x-y\rvert<\varepsilon\implies\bigl\lvert f(x)-f(y)\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: You want MVT, not IVT.

Comment: @Jose  carlos  sir    i have  one  confusion that   we know  that $log (1+x^2) \le x^2 $   but $f(x) = x^2  $is  not   uniformly continious on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @zhw. Right. Thank you.

Comment: @jasmine I don't understand your comment.

Comment: oks  @JoséCarlosSantos again  im uploading a  new  question    ..pliz have a looks,,, same pattern question

Comment: But did you understand my answer to **this** question?

Comment: yes  i understand  ur answer

Comment: pliz  see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190038/is-f-nx-is-uniformly-convergent-on-mathbbr